# how to call stored procedure using codeigniter?

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter, stored-procedures, jqgrid

How to call stored procedure using codeigniter ? help me, please

```
function ViewSchedule($dt_dari,$dt_to,$dt_org,$dt_emp){
        $result = $this->db->query("exec dailyAttdCrossTab '".$dt_dari."','".$dt_to."','".$dt_org."','".$dt_emp."'");

        return $result;
    }
```

Comment: It is going to be hard to help you. Please clearly articulate the error or problem you are running into.

Answer (score 0):

you can call stored procedure as below

```
$this->db->query("call test_proc()");
```